# NHibernate's Increment Generator - could not fetch initial value

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to use **NHibernate** (and **FluentNHibernate**) over a legacy database.
I'm also using **SQLite for tests**.

When I try to create a **test for the mappings** using FluentNHibernate's **PersistenceSpecification**, I get the following exception:

**NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException : could not fetch initial value for increment generator**

I'm mapping my ID like this:

```
Id(f => f.ID, "OID").GeneratedBy.Increment();
```

My test uses SQLite, so when I ran them, the tables are initially empty.

Does someone have an idea how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 4):

You can also try:

```
Id(f => f.ID, "OID").GeneratedBy.Native()
```

This works for me in SQLite & SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using GeneratedBy.Identity instead of GeneratedBy.Increment?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [seqhilo](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator) depending on your database system.